# Como recuperar uma base de dados em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tive um problema num cliente que o sistema operativo deixou de funcionar. 
Consegui aceder ao disco e nele está uma base de dados MySQL dentro da pasta `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\BDados` que contém os ficheiros `.FRM` e `.IDB`.

Como é que consigo recuperar essa base de dados?

Já copiei os ficheiros dessa pasta para a pasta do meu computador mas não consigo aceder. Quando entro pelo MySQL Workbench as tabelas aparecem mas não consigo aceder ao conteúdo. Dá sempre o erro:

> Error Code: 1812. Tablespace is missing for table `bdados`.`clientes`

Gostaria de ter a vossa ajuda para resolver esta situação.

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma dica nesse [site](https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-tablespace-is-missing-for-table/) que pode te ajudar:

Primeiro você cria uma nova base de dados com as tabelas.

Depois exclua os arquivos recém criados usando a instrução DISCARD

```
ALTER TABLE newdb.table1 DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

Em seguida, copie todos os arquivos .ibd e .frm do backup para a pasta do banco de dados, depois acesse o banco de dados.

Peça ao MySQL para aceitar os novos arquivos usando a instrução IMPORT.

```
ALTER TABLE newdb.table1 IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

Isso pode ajudar a recuperar as tabelas do banco de dados.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Como é que atribuo a propriedade mysql:mysql?

Comment: Editei a reposta, no caso você tem que acessar seu database para fazer as alterações seguintes. Tomara que isso possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: Quais são as alterações que sugere? Já fiz o que me indicou até ao ALTER TABLE. Aí deu-me o seguinte erro: Error Code: 1815. Internal error: Cannot reset LSNs in table `bdados`.`clientes` : Unsupported 0.157 sec

Comment: Já tentei tudo e não consegui nada. O pc onde estavam os dados tem instalado o MySQL 8. Arranjei um outro pc e instalei o MySQL 8 também. Segui as instruções todas. Quando executo a instrução ALTER TABLE mewdb.table1 IMPORT TABLESPACE; dá o seguinte erro: ALTER TABLE newdb.table1 IMPORT TABLESPACE Error Code: 1034. Incorrect key file for table 'table1'; try to repair it. Conseguem-me ajudar com este erro?

Comment: Preciso mesmo da vossa ajuda nesta situação. Já experimentei com vários parâmetros e dá sempre este esso

Comment: Você está usando algum programa? Ou esta indo direto pelo terminal/DOS?

Comment: Estou a utilizar o MySQL Workbench

Comment: Ok, então, o que entendi é que quando você cria uma nova base de dados para recuperar os dados do arquivo .frm e .ibd é preciso encontrar o ID da tabela em que o MySQL está atualmente configurado, assim como o ID da  tabela que precisa ser recuperar. Dá uma olhada nesse linq: http://www.chriscalender.com/tag/innodb-error-tablespace-id-in-file/

Comment: O erro na recuperação esta acontecendo porque o ID da tabela atual do MySQL não correspondesse ao id da tabela ibd preexistente.

Comment: Fiz aquilo que o link diz mas no ponto 2.E o erro que me dá não é "ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error -1 from storage engine" mas sim o erro "ERROR 1812 (HY000): Tablespace is missing for table `test1`.`product`." Não consegui chegar ao ponto onde se sabe qual o ID para depois o poder "acertar"

Comment: Então é porque não há essa tabela no banco de dados que você quer recuperar, eu ainda não precisei fazer isso, e estou sem tempo para testar, mas você sabe o nome de todas as tabelas que você tem nesse banco que você quer recuperar? Se você tiver algum script de criação, você monta um novo banco de dados com a mesma estrutura do banco a ser recuperado, daí você vai conseguir recuperar esses dados seguindo os passos seguintes após montar o banco.